# Split string to array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to split a string `dynamically` that may have different format(a:b,a.b,a/b) to an array of two elements.For example :

```
string :- abs:sba;//array[0]='abs';array[1]='sba';
string :- abs.sba;//array[0]='abs';array[1]='sba';
string :- abs/sba;//array[0]='abs';array[1]='sba';
```

I have tried with `string.split(':');` method,but it will not be applicable for the next two cases.I need a solution which split the string dynamically.

Comment: use the delimiter ":"

Comment: You forgot the second paragraph: _"This is what I tried but it didn't work: `code`"_

Comment: is it always split by the middle?

Comment: Do you have a list of valid delimiters?

Comment: You should have a list of delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** to specify multiple delimiters in a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**:

```
yourString.split(/[:;,\/]/);
```

Specify all possible delimiters inside `[]` in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function:

```
var arr = str.split(/[:.\/]/);
```

OR if you want to split the string using any non-word character then use:

```
var arr = str.split(/\W/);
```